# Execute multi provider even the previous one executes successfully in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm new with spring and I'm setting up Authentication in my application. I need to execute two providers if and only if the first executes successfully.

The problem: When the first provider is authenticated, the second not execute. I'm using a ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider first, then I need to execute a CustomProvider.

That is my code:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AdWebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  ...

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
  {
      //ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider
      auth.authenticationProvider(AdAuthConfig.getLdapProvider());

      //CustomProvider
      auth.authenticationProvider(AdAuthConfig.getDbProvider());        

  }
}
```

```java
//LDAP Provider
public static ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider getLdapProvider()
{
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adProvider = 
        new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(AD_DOMAIN, AD_URL);

        adProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        adProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);

        adProvider.setSearchFilter(USER_PATTERN);
        adProvider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper());

        return adProvider;
    }
```

```java
//CustomAuthenticationProvider
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider
    implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService service;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate( Authentication authentication ) throws AuthenticationException {

        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        //AdUserDetails is a custom UserDetail
        AdUserDetails userDetails = (AdUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();

        boolean authenticated = 
                service.authenticateEmployeeNumber(userDetails.getEmployeeNumber());

        authentication.setAuthenticated(authenticated);

        if(!authenticated) {

            throw new BadCredentialsException("Employee Number(" + 
                    userDetails.getEmployeeNumber() + 
                    "not found!"); 
        }

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }



}
```

Thanks for ur time.

Comment: What is `getDbProvider()`?

Comment: @Nikolas, this method returns a instance of CustomAuthenticationProvider. Sorry about this mistake

Comment: Spring security is designed that way - if the first authentication provider throws an authentication exception, only then the second auth provider will be executed. Can you explain more, what do you want exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Adil. I need authenticate with LDAP provider (that part is ok) and then I need to check the employee Number (received in my Custom UserDetails from LDAP) in a database (in the code it's the Second provider).

Comment: Move the 'check the employee Number' part to the userDetails service as well, so you can perform the check in both auth providers.